# Laravel 4 Model only works if i take another name for the class and file

Tags: php, model, laravel, laravel-4

**Hello i have a Controller:**

```
class AddressController extends BaseController {

    public function showIndex()
    {
        $address = Postcode::all();
        return 'hello';
    }
```

**And a Model (which doesn't work):**

```
class Postcode extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'postcode';
}
```

**But it only works with another name like:**

```
class Kla extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'postcode';  
}
```

**Anybody knows why?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have named something else in the root namespace as `Postcode`. Most common this is the database migration. This is why database migrations generally should be a class name describing what it is doing, so in your case `CreatePostcodeTable`.

This is also why you should be using namespaces.

Just to be clear in-case you don't understand namespaces. You have 2 classes with the same name. The composer autoloader has grabbed the first one it finds (the one that isn't your model) and tried to use it. There is no static method `all` on the other class so you get an error (which you should have pasted in your question).